# Trying to make navigation centered on phones and right aligned on large screens

Tags: css

I am trying to get my navigation to be centered on phones but aligned right on larger screens. I am using flex-box for my navigation. Below is my css code:

```
    z-index: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: black;
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp). This allows you to define cut off points of the screen size and give each screen size unique CSS properties. So you can just rearrange your layout at a certain size, which you should be able to do on your own.